# Событие для checkbox

Tags: checkbox, события, html, javascript

Есть у нас, скажем 3 checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkin1" class="checking" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkin2" class="checking" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkin3" class="checking" value="3">
```

Мне нужно, чтобы при выборе чекбокса, в массив checklist(на js), добавлялся элемент в конец, равный value, тип int. А при снятии чекбокса элемент удалялся из массива. Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать эту мечту?

Comment: Вы хотите поставить рекорд по задаванию однотипных вопросов в единицу времени? Покажите, пожалуйста, что вы сделали сами и что у вас не получилось. Выкладывайте код на [jsfiddle.net][1]

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: ок - а можно ваши контакты?

Comment: Какие контакты? Это не сайт фрилансеров, а форум, где помогают решать задачи, НО не выполнять задачи за другого.

Comment: я бы выложил код, но там php не держит, а у меня все формы генерит php

Comment: так вы сделайте **пример** а не то что у вас там php генерит.

Comment: а ну ок - я кажется разобрался

Comment: Если разобрались, то выкладывайте сюда. Мб кому-то пригодится ваше решение и подобных вопросов никто задавать не будет

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот что получилось у меня http://jsfiddle.net/RSbHV/

> ```
> var arr = [];
> var i = 0;
> $(":checkbox").change(function(){
>     if(this.checked){
>         arr[i] = $(this).val();
>         i++;
>     }else{
>         var val = $(this).val();
>         var index = arr.indexOf(val);
>         arr.splice(index, 1);
>         i--;
>     }
>     console.log(arr);
> });
> ```

Comment: @ZondArt, можно и [покороче сделать][1]

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/RSbHV/6/

Comment: У вас не так работает, как просил ТС. При нажатии на чекбокс — его значение должно попадать в конец массива, а у вас они по порядку выстраиваются: ["1", "2", "3"] всегда.

Answer (score 3):

1. http://jsfiddle.net/aSdS4/ — jQuery
2. http://jsfiddle.net/aSdS4/1/ — modern browsers

Comment: Добрый день. Мне подошел ваш код на jquery. Подскажите, если у меня несколько блоков с чекбоксами на стрнаице - как мне для каждого блока свой массив формировать?